# Why is this code working in jsfiddle but not in my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've never had this problem before. I have this code that I am trying to implement into my application http://jsfiddle.net/TC6Gr/119/

I have tried

1. Pasting all the jsfiddle code in a new page without my code, it doesn't work.
2. Wrap/unwrap the script in `$(document).ready...` it doesn't work.
3. When I put an alert in the click function, the alert displays but doesn't display the modal?

Comment: Did you include the bootstrap and bootstrap.datepicker javascript?

Comment: Are you really including 3 different versions?

Comment: I dont see jquery 2.1.0 being included...

Comment: Could you just post the whole parts of the HTML that are relevant to the problem? Would make finding the error a lot faster..

Comment: Actually... it's probably because the `<link>` is not right.. should be in this format `<link href='...url...' rel='stylesheet' />`

Answer (score 2):

You are including JQuery 1.10.2, JSFiddle is using jquery 2.1.0

Also JSFiddle is including the following libraries

```
bootstrap.min.css 
-(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css)
bootstrap.min.js
-(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js)
bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
-(https://rawgit.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js)
bootstrap-datetimepicker.css
-(https://rawgit.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css)
```

So try including...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link src ="https://rawgit.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"></link>
<link src ="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<script src ="https://rawgit.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src ="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is this a public site that you could share so we could inspect it?

Comment: bootstrap.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
test.php:134 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: make sure jquery is included before bootstrap

Comment: The last and first `<script>` in your answer should have been a `<link>` for css

Comment: still not working guys, it keeps saying there's an error in the jquery file.

Comment: ahh... put the datetime before the bootstrap

Comment: @abcdefghijklmnop please put the full `<head>` you used in your question.

Comment: you are missing the jQuery, the one you had before from google libraries

Answer (score 0):

So try starting here, its not fully complete but I can get the modal to show up with this:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link src ="https://rawgit.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"></link>
    <script src ="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="https://rawgit.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link src ="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top:20px;
        }
        .start-date {
            padding-left:0;
        }
        .end-date {
            padding-right:0;
        }
        .date>input:hover,.date>input:hover {
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        .time-help {
            margin-top:40px;
        }
        @media(max-width:767px) {
            .start-date {
                padding:0 0 5px 0;
            }
            .end-date {
                padding:5px 0 0 0;
            }
            .time-help {
                margin-top:10px;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#time-start').datetimepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii',
            autoclose: true,
            pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
            maxView: 3,
            minuteStep: 1,
            endDate: new Date()
        })

        $('#time-end').datetimepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii',
            autoclose: true,
            pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
            maxView: 3,
            minuteStep: 1,
            endDate: new Date()
        })

         $("td#my_clickable_cell").bind("click",function() {

              $('#myModal').modal('show');
           });
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td >Name</td>
            <td>Sunday</td>
            <td>Monday</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
            <td>Name1</td>
            <td id="my_clickable_cell" data-value="1">16:00-18:00</td>
            <td id="my_clickable_cell" data-value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name2</td>
            <td id="my_clickable_cell" data-value="3"></td>
            <td id="my_clickable_cell" data-value="3">16:00-18:00</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
    <form class="form-group col-sm-12" role="form">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Times</label>

      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="col-sm-6 start-date">
          <div class='input-group date' id="time-start">
            <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Start Time" readonly>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 end-date">
          <div class='input-group date' id="time-end">
            <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="End Time" readonly>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <p class="help-block time-help">Select start and end times</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Seth, thanks for your help! It's working now! However, it's not displaying the way it is in the fiddle :/

Answer (score 0):

more than a few errors in your code
1. the modal pop-up is not hidden on page load - try hiding that with css first.
2. the jquery function(datetime-picker) may not work for you. - you can however just use  and html includes a datetime picker for you
check [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) for more info on that

try those and let me know what error you have on your developer's console - I assume you are using chrome browser.

Comment: use <input type="datetime-local>

Comment: the function - datetimepicker is deprecated

Comment: what have you modified, and what is the status of the output now?

Comment: by style, do you mean the css display? if yes, you figure that out.  as for the datepicker/datebase thing, could you be more specific?